# Manager role not function as expected

Tags: moodle

I read the moodle user:update document.  The Manager supposed to have the update user profile permission.

I have assigned a user with Manager systemwide role.

I checked on the Manager role on moodle/user:update, it is set to Allow.

I checked on the user permission, moodle/user:update is set to No

The user is inheriting the following roles.

Manager in System
Authenticated user in System
Can someone give me a clue? or is there any tools I can use to debug which rules override the status?

Thanks.

Comment: its a bug.   https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-50917

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug.  The fix will be released next week.
I am using version Moodle 2.8.3+ (Build: 20150205).

https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-50917